# React - Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate

I am trying to set the state "error with a string value inside the PostData function with the this.setState() command as shown below but when debugging I see 'this' is undefined and therefore setState is not assigning the string to the error variable in the `state`. Its like `this` loses scope inside the Postdata function.

I have seen similar questions on StackOverflow in which the issue is solved by properly binding the function applying the setState, this is not my case as the function signup is bound.

```
class Signup extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: '',
            confirmPassword: '',
            email: '',
            name: '',
            error: '',
            redirectToReferrer: false
        };

        this.signup = this.signup.bind(this)
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
    }


    signup() {
        PostData('signup', this.state).then((result) => {
            let responseJson = result
            console.log(responseJson.message)
            if (responseJson.message.indexOf("registration success") > -1) {
                sessionStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(responseJson))
                this.setState({ redirectToReferrer: true });
            } else {
                let string = responseJson.message[0]
                this.setState({ error: string })
            }

        });
    }


    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.redirectToReferrer || sessionStorage.getItem('userData')) {
            return (<Redirect to={'/home'} />)
        }



        return (

            <div className="row " id="Body">
                <div className="medium-5 columns left">
                    <h4>Signup</h4>
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" onChange={this.onChange} />
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" onChange={this.onChange} />
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" onChange={this.onChange} />
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" onChange={this.onChange} />
                    <label>Confirm Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" onChange={this.onChange} />

                    <input type="submit" className="button" value="Sign Up" onClick={this.signup} />
                    <a href="/login">Login</a>
                    <input name="error" onChange={this.onChange}></input>
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Signup
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might have something to do with the scope of your function. Your `this.setState` is wrapped with another arrow function. You can wrap your `setState` in another function, but put into the top level with the class.

Could you try put into an arrow function for your `onClick` event.